# Unity LitJson.JsonData exception on cast in foreach loop

Tags: c#, exception, unityscript, litjson

I got the following exception in the `foreach` statement of my code snippet below:

> exception:System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

I took a closer look at `LitJson.JsonData`. It does have the `internal class OrderedDictionaryEnumerator : IDictionaryEnumerator` implementation. I am not sure what is missing. Any ideas?

```
protected static IDictionary<string, object> JsonToDictionary(JsonData in_jsonObj)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JsonData> child in in_jsonObj)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LitJson.JsonData` class is declared as:

```
public class JsonData : IJsonWrapper, IEquatable<JsonData>
```

Where the `IJsonWrapper` in turn derives from these two interfaces: [`System.Collections.IList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`System.Collections.Specialized.IOrderedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.iordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Note that both of these are the ***non-generic*** collection versions. When enumerating you are not going to get a `KeyValuePair<>` as the result. Instead, it will be a [`System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance.

So you will have to change your `foreach` to:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry child in in_jsonObj)
{
    // access to key
    object key = child.Key;
    // access to value
    object value = child.Value;

    ...

    // or, if you know the types:
    var key = child.Key as string;
    var value = child.Values as JsonData;
}
```